# Color Game (Counter Loop not running)

Tags: java, processing

I've been trying to figure out for the life of me why my counter loop isn't running. I have this snippet of my code that will not run even when I qualify the requirements of it being that (counter>=10). It should run the line saying that I lost the Game but it won't do so regardless. I initially thought it was because the counter was within the loop and since it'll keep going it won't ever meet the condition but even then it still won't go. My apologize if its not the best looking code far as spacing goes I'm still new to coding

```
void draw ()
{
  int name=5, strikes=1;

  int [][] scores= new int [name][strikes];
  int score1=0;

  keyPressed();
  {
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
      first();
      if (key == 'r' || key == 'R')
      {
        secoend();
      }

      if (key != 'r' || key != 'R')
      {
        score1++;
      } else if (score1>=10)
      {
        background(255);
        String text="You Lost the Game";
        text(text, 411, 90);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can format your code in the Processing editor by pressing CTRL+T

Comment: I'm not sure why you call the `keyPressed()` method and initialize stuff in the `draw()` loop. It kinda scares me. You should post your whole code, you may have a more improvements to make than it looks.

Answer (score 2):

This if-statement is **always true**, and so it will never enter the else-branch:

```
 if (key != 'r' || key != 'R')
```

`key` can only be one thing so either of those is always true

I think you ment:

```
if (key != 'r' && key != 'R')
```

Comment: Ok but now its going straight to saying I lost the game

Comment: You lose the game immediately because you check the key input *before* the loop, then the loop runs 10 times in a row and you end up losing the game. (I think, not sure what `keyPressed()`, `first()` or `second()` do )

Answer (score 1):

Check your if statements, you're always incrementing score1 because `if(key != 'r' || key != 'R')` will always be true.

Comment: I changed my last statement to an && like RobCo said and it now just goes straight to saying I lost the Game. Do you have any ideas why that is?

Comment: At the begining of the for loop, you can just `System.out.println(key);` this might be helpful